# SQL tracing not working for JPA persistence.xml

Tags: sql, logging, jpa-2.0

Here is a line I included under the properties node of my persistence.xml file

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="File=C:\Users/PS7/IBM/wid7/workspace/Logs/openjpa.SQL.log DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
```

I want all SQL queries to go to that log file. But no file goes there and thus no SQL queries.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about how one would represent a windows-path here, but I think what you wrote is a typo. My best guess would be:

```
<property name="openjpa.Log" value="File=C:/Users/PS7/IBM/wid7/workspace/Logs/openjpa.SQL.log DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
```

(Switched the \ to / at C:)

If there is nothing wrong with the path, it is possible the jvm doesn't have write privileges to that file/directory - or the securitymanager doesn't allow the logging code to write there - which should be seen on stderr, by just naming a simple file without path and then searching for it.

Comment: sorry,  that was just a type in when I tried to write up the question.

Comment: still haven't solved this, I was looking into the admin console to see if that had some kind of security setting I was unaware of.  But I have since been distracted as the problem that I was trying to trace has been resolved.  It would still be nice to figure this out.  I will investigate and let you know.